# Appying a binary threshold filter on a rgb image opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a binary Mat obtained by thresholding. I need to apply this binary Mat on a rgb Mat.
Is there a method in opencv to apply a binary mask on a rgb image?

Comment: You mean like this? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532924/opencv-bitwise-and-mask

Comment: I do not understand, what you are trying to accomplish. Can you be more specific? Do you want to perform a convolution? Do you want to use the binary mat as a mask/alpha channel?

Comment: I obtained the binary mask by obtaining the threshold(distance, mask, 35, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

Answer (score 3):

Just use [bitwise_and](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) function:

```
Mat dest;
bitwise_and(rgbMat, binaryMat, dest);
```

it should work, but if not, just use [cvtColor](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor) function to convert `binaryMat` to BGR:

```
cvtColor(binaryMat, binaryMat, CV_GRAY2BGR); //but this before bitwise_and function
```